# Trinidad tables are acting awfully screwy, multiple results, growing on refresh

Tags: apache, html-table, myfaces, trinidad

I'm working on a MyFaces site for a project. It's using Trinidad, Tobago, Tomahawk, tested on a Tomcat server (T seems to be their favorite letter). Everything is more or less working fine and up to date. Much of the site is constructed. However, I'm hitting some very strange behavior when trying to use tr: table. The bean will pass it an arraylist of object, which has the fields listed in each column. The thing is, each field is being listed 3 times. If I have two objects in the collection, they each get printed 3 times alternating, giving six rows in the table. I am utterly baffled as to why this is happening. Furthermore, refreshing the page makes the table multiply in size, doubling the already too-many rows! I played with the rows="2" property to try and constrain it, but it would grow every time I selected the next page!

The bean code is about as simple as it gets, manually constructing two objects, placing them in the list, and returning the list. I've verified that the list is only two entries long. The trinidad code is thus:

```
<tr:table value="#{acctManageBean.allEmployees}" var="stat">
<tr:column headerText="Name">
    <tr:outputText value="#{stat.name}"/>
  </tr:column>
  <tr:column headerText="Last">
    <tr:outputText value="#{stat.number}"/>
  </tr:column>
</tr:table>
```

I'm only using quick and dirty test data here, but I am completely stymied by the triplicate behavior.

Comment: Could you provide the beancode as well?